# d3 bl.ocks polar clock ex questions

Tags: javascript, d3.js

There's a great d3 polar clock example here - http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1096355.

I've a couple of questions about what's going on under the hood if anyone's kind enough to spare a moment to explain them.

1.

```
d3.transition().duration(0).each(tick);
```

From the documentation this essentially is the equivalent to

```
d3.select(document).transition().duration(0).each(tick)
```

So should this initially control the transition of the document in to view? I've tried giving duration a value > 0 and it acts like a delay rather than animating anything. I've tried adding some content to the tick fn to control animating elements in to view but it never seems to animate anything. A working example of how this is different from just calling tick() would be useful.

2.

```
function tick() {
  field = field
      .each(function(d) { this._value = d.value; })
      .data(fields)
      .each(function(d) { d.previousValue = this._value; });
```

This may make more sense if I understand 1. better however the main aspect I don't understand is how 'this' is being utilised. d.value is being copied to this._value. 'this' is the HTML dom element? I've tried a console.log(this) directly beneath this line of code and it doesn't show any _value property. 
An explanation of what's going on here would be appreciated. The fundamental differences between this and d in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In this case, it's functionally equivalent to simply calling `tick()` (see [modified example](http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/bda82d92f7895a5b67a2)). The advantage of using `d3.transition()` that I can see is that you're associating some metadata on the transition with the document element, which is not the case when you're simply calling the function. In principle, you can then use this metadata to e.g. stop the transition, although it's not being used to that effect in the example.
2. `d` refers to the data bound to the `g` elements in `field`, whereas `this` refers to the actual DOM elements. You can't see that in the console because the expression that is printed is not evaluated at the time of printing, but when you expand it. That is, what you're looking at when you're inspecting the console isn't what was there when the value was printed.

What the code does is save the previous value with the DOM element (which is necessary as the data (`d`) is being changed through the call to `.data()`) to be able to transition properly between different values (see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410) for another case where it is necessary to access the previous value).

Comment: *"You can't see that in the console because the expression that is printed is not evaluated at the time of printing, but when you expand it."* This is not correct. I have checked this behaviour in the console in FF, IE11 and Chrome. All of these are evaluating the expression at the time of printing. Thus, you might very well check for existence using `console.log(this.hasOwnProperty("_value"))` or print the value using `console.log(this._value)`.

Comment: It sounds like OP is logging `this` and expanding it later.